# Newton.JSON convert dynamic object to JObject instead of dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
string  result ="{"AppointmentID":463236,"Message":"Successfully Appointment Booked","Success":true,"MessageCode":200,"isError":false,"Exception":null,"ReturnedValue":null}"

   dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
```

d.GetType ()   is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

so how to deserialize it to dynamic object instead of JObject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite clear what is not working for you and why you care about the return type but you could directly access the properties of the deserialized object like this:

```
string result = @"{""AppointmentID"":463236,""Message"":""Successfully Appointment Booked"",""Success"":true,""MessageCode"":200,""isError"":false,""Exception"":null,""ReturnedValue"":null}";
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);

string message = d.Message;
int code = d.MessageCode;
...
```

Comment: I cant access property directly because "d" is not dynamic object , but it is JObject so it will throw exception

Comment: `"d" is not dynamic object`: WRONG. `d` is a dynamic object because you declared it as `dynamic` and you can access any property you like. The `JObject` class has this nice property to automatically dispatch calls to its properties. Did you even try the code I have shown in my answer?

Comment: that is the first impression when you didn't actually tried the code , try to execute that code and you will get error on string message = d.Message; because "Message" does not exists, and that is my issue

Comment: I executed the code before posting it here and it worked fine for me.

Comment: you are right ,I executed the code outside of unit test and it worked, but inside unit test it converting it to JObject , that is weird

Comment: i can confirm this happens in some cases where the resulting object is JObject and any late bound property access results in a binder exception. this does not occur when i feed a well formed json string into the deserializeobject method in a unit test, but happens consistently when deserializing live traffic.

it's not clear why this happens.

Comment: interesting, seems this happens whenever i deserialize a structured object which contains an array element, for example { "id": 1, "fail":["val1","val2"] }returns JObject and any late bound access results in a runtime binder exception

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like

```
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
```

This might also suit your needs (untested)

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
```